# Learning kanji readings with examples

Tags: readings, dictionary, resources

As background, I haven't really focused on learning kanji. I've mainly focused on learning words, and just using the correct characters for those words (purely typing, I don't write kanji by hand). However, I want to be a little more proficient with kanji, by learning a kanji and its reading whenever I encounter a new kanji or a new reading, by learning at least one other example of that kanji with the same reading.

I can look up a kanji with jisho.org, and find examples of a given reading by clicking on a reading. For example, if I'm interested in [相](http://jisho.org/search/%E7%9B%B8) from the word "結婚相談所" and the on-yomi "ソウ", I can can click on "ソウ" and it takes me to [相 そう](http://jisho.org/search/%E7%9B%B8%20%E3%81%9D%E3%81%86). However, while jisho.org mentions which words are "common", I'm worried that some words given might be words I should avoid at my stage of learning, because they're less common than other words with a similar meaning.

Are there any resources (preferably online) that I can use to look up a kanji and its reading and get well curated examples of that reading being used?

Answer (score 2):

Kanjicards has online (and printable) lists sorted by grade level, JLPT level or frequency of use.
The lists include both types of readings, example words and stroke order:
http://kanjicards.org/kanji-lists.html

Your rep's quite a bit ahead of mine, so you might be looking for something more advanced... but I've found that those lists are useful for familiarizing myself with the kanji (although I remember the readings best by just... reading.)

Comment: The resource looks interesting, but the page [kanji cards](http://kanjicards.org/download-kanji-cards.html) gives the warnings "The selection of example words might not the optimum for [studying] purposes" and "Rarely used readings might be included".

Comment: The example words are aren't curated by frequency of use, but they DO show most or all of the ways a kanji can be read (including the unusual readings). It's more a kanji learning resource than a word learning resource, which may or may not be what you're looking for. With that said, I do believe the readings themselves are listed from most common to least common. At least, it sure seems that way.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an online resource, but the book よく使う順 漢字2200 presents the kanji in frequency of use order and lists some of the most common words for each.

https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E5%AD%A6%E7%BF%92%E3%81%AE%E3%81%9F%E3%82%81%E3%81%AE-%E3%82%88%E3%81%8F%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%86%E9%A0%86-%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%972200-%E5%BE%B3%E5%BC%98-%E5%BA%B7%E4%BB%A3/dp/438514074X